# 'Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Single and System.String.'

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, sql-like

i am building a win form app using access database as data-source , and in the search button of my winform i have this code"

```
private void searchAccessDatabase()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(KeywordTextBox.Text.Trim()))
            {
                Refreshdata();
                return;
            }
            string strkeyword = KeywordTextBox.Text.Trim().ToString();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat("(Convert(ID,'System.String') LIKE '" + "{0}" + "')", strkeyword);
            sb.AppendFormat("OR (Customer_Name LIKE '*" + "{0}" + "*')", strkeyword);
            sb.AppendFormat("OR (Complaint_Number LIKE '*" + "{0}" + "*')", strkeyword);
            sb.AppendFormat("(Convert(Size,'System.String') LIKE '" + "{0}" + "')", strkeyword);
            sb.AppendFormat("OR (Material_Number LIKE '*" + "{0}" + "*')", strkeyword);
            sb.AppendFormat("OR (Nature_Of_Problem LIKE '*" + "{0}" + "*')", strkeyword);
            sb.AppendFormat("OR (Spool_Type LIKE '*" + "{0}" + "*')", strkeyword);
            string strFilter = sb.ToString();
           material_Return_DataBindingSource.Filter = strFilter;

            if (material_Return_DataBindingSource.Count != 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = material_Return_DataBindingSource;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Records Found", "Search Result", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                Refreshdata();
                return;
            }
        }
```

But during running the below error is coming :
'Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Single and System.String.'

I know that the error is related to the format type of the cells and the search type i am using but i am unable to correct them as i am still learning on this : Anybody please correct me where i am wrong.

This is the sample data table : which will help you see the sample data i am entering to the table , with which i want to search
[image: Sample data table]

Comment: I've always wondered, and never got a straight answer, why do people stop and start strings on the same line? Why this `"(Convert(ID,'System.String') LIKE '" + "{0}" + "')"` and not this `"(Convert(ID,'System.String') LIKE '{0}')"`

Comment: Doing `.Filter = string.Format("Convert(ID,'System.String') LIKE '{0}' OR Customer_Name LIKE '*{0}*' OR Complaint_Number LIKE '*{0}*' OR Convert([Size],'System.String' LIKE '{0}') OR Material_Number LIKE '*{0}*' OR Nature_Of_Problem LIKE '*{0}*' OR Spool_Type LIKE '*{0}*'");` would be a lot more readable, especially if you just create a single multi line string and put one OR per line. I note the only things that look like singles (the qty columns) aren't in your filter. Are you showing us the full code?

Comment: Thank you for your response , actually i don't want the number columns to be filtered , however i want the size column to be filtered which is single hence i have added into the code.

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm guessing he didn't know, he did say he was learning so I'm guessing he was treating a 'Format()' like a native string, I did put this in my reply below with a bunch of other stuff including the missing OR conditional.


Ravi, Have you tried filtering by one of the lines at a time and see which one stuffs up?

Comment: *actually I don't want the number columns to be filtered* - then why does the filter spec contain reference to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. test with and without the convert statements
2. You don't have any * to signify where the string similarity can end eg: `Name LIKE '*test*'` will get every record with test in the Name field regardless of what is before or after it, where `Name LIKE 'test*` will get you only the ones where Name field starts with test.

The fact you are stating it is 'like' something without any wildcards or other signifiers may be causing issues.

Try just making them equal and see if it errors out.

Also you do not need the + in your string format for multiple strings as the sb.format works without them.

```
 sb.AppendFormat("(Convert(ID,'System.String') LIKE '" + "{0}" + "')", strkeyword);
```

can be written as

```
 sb.AppendFormat("(Convert(ID,'System.String') LIKE '{0}')", strkeyword);
```

I also not that the following line does not have and OR at the start which may be causing an error.

```
 sb.AppendFormat("(Convert(Size,'System.String') LIKE '" + "{0}" + "')", strkeyword);
```

Maybe update your question with the final string that results from your append when it errors out.

Comment: Hi slipoch thank you so much for your response , as you said the missing or was the problem and also in place of * i replaced with %  and now it is doing good .

Comment: Awesomesauce! Glad to hear it helped.